# How can resolve: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification

Tags: android, listview, exception, android-listview, adapter

I have this exception on my APP... I don't know why happen it.

**java.lang.IllegalStateException:** 
The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread.

In `ListView(2131492879)`, class `android.widget.ListView` with Adapter class `com.agencialanave.AdaptadorListaApps`

I have tried many options but I have not managed to fix it.

**Class: Apps.java**

```
public class Apps
{
    public Bitmap Colorbanda;
    public Bitmap Logo;
    public Bitmap LogoBasura;
    public String NombreAPP;
    public float MemoriaUsada;
    public String NombrePaquete;
    public File Apk;

    public Apps(Bitmap colorbanda, Bitmap logo,String nombreAPP, float memoriaUsada, Bitmap logoBasura, String nombrePaquete, File apk) 
    {
        super();
        Colorbanda = colorbanda;
        Logo = logo;
        LogoBasura = logoBasura;
        NombreAPP = nombreAPP;
        MemoriaUsada = memoriaUsada;
        NombrePaquete = nombrePaquete;
        Apk = apk;
    }

    public Apps(Bitmap colorbanda, Bitmap logo,String nombreAPP, float memoriaUsada, Bitmap logoBasura, String nombrePaquete) 
    {
        super();
        Colorbanda = colorbanda;
        Logo = logo;
        LogoBasura = logoBasura;
        NombreAPP = nombreAPP;
        MemoriaUsada = memoriaUsada;
        NombrePaquete = nombrePaquete;
    }

    public Bitmap getColorbanda() {
        return Colorbanda;
    }

    public void setColorbanda(Bitmap colorbanda) {
        Colorbanda = colorbanda;
    }

    public Bitmap getLogo() {
        return Logo;
    }

    public void setLogo(Bitmap logo) {
        Logo = logo;
    }

    public Bitmap getLogoBasura() {
        return LogoBasura;
    }

    public void setLogoBasura(Bitmap logoBasura) {
        LogoBasura = logoBasura;
    }

    public String getNombreAPP() {
        return NombreAPP;
    }

    public void setNombreAPP(String nombreAPP) {
        NombreAPP = nombreAPP;
    }

    public float getMemoriaUsada() {
        return MemoriaUsada;
    }

    public void setMemoriaUsada(float memoriaUsada) {
        MemoriaUsada = memoriaUsada;
    }

    public String getNombrePaquete() {
        return NombrePaquete;
    }

    public void setNombrePaquete(String nombrePaquete) {
        NombrePaquete = nombrePaquete;
    }

    public File getApk() {
        return Apk;
    }

    public void setApk(File apk) {
        Apk = apk;
    }
}
```

**Class: AdaptadorListaApps.java**

```
public class AdaptadorListaApps extends ArrayAdapter<Apps>
{
    private static Activity Context;
    ArrayList<Apps> listaApps;

    public AdaptadorListaApps(Activity context, ArrayList<Apps> lista) 
    {
        super(context, R.layout.layout_list, lista);
        Context = context;

        listaApps = lista;
    }

    class ViewHolder
    {
        ImageView fotoBandaColor,fotoLogoApp,fotoDelete;
        TextView nombreApp, memoriaUsada;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        View item =convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (item == null)
        {

            LayoutInflater inflater = Context.getLayoutInflater();
            item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_list, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.fotoBandaColor = (ImageView)item.findViewById(R.id.bandaColor);
            holder.fotoLogoApp = (ImageView)item.findViewById(R.id.logoApp);
            holder.fotoDelete = (ImageView)item.findViewById(R.id.borrarApp);
            holder.nombreApp = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.nombreApp);
            holder.memoriaUsada = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.memoriaUsada);

            item.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder=(ViewHolder) item.getTag();
        }

        holder.fotoBandaColor.setImageBitmap(listaApps.get(position).getColorbanda());
        holder.fotoLogoApp.setImageBitmap(listaApps.get(position).getLogo());
        holder.fotoDelete.setImageBitmap(listaApps.get(position).getLogoBasura());
        holder.memoriaUsada.setText(TamañoAppEnRam(listaApps.get(position).getMemoriaUsada()) + " MB  ( " + PorcentageMemoria(listaApps.get(position).getMemoriaUsada())+"% )");

        if(listaApps.get(position).getMemoriaUsada() < 4)
        {
            holder.memoriaUsada.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#56E000"));
        }
        else if(listaApps.get(position).getMemoriaUsada() > 7)
        {
            holder.memoriaUsada.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }                   
        else
        {
            holder.memoriaUsada.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF8000"));
        }

        holder.nombreApp.setText(listaApps.get(position).getNombreAPP());


        return item;
    }
}
```

**Code where update listview**

```
private class GetRunningApps extends AsyncTask<String, ArrayList<Apps>, String> 
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) throws IllegalStateException
        {
            listaapps.clear();
            listaapps = new ArrayList<Apps>();

            cont = 0;

            ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningTasks = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
            PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

            Drawable icon;
            Bitmap logo;
            float memoria = 0;
            String nombrePaquete;
            MB = 0;

            int pids[] = new int[1];

            adaptadorLista = new AdaptadorListaApps(activity,listaapps);

            for (RunningAppProcessInfo appInfo : runningTasks) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    if(appInfo.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_SERVICE || appInfo.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_BACKGROUND)
                    {
                        icon = pm.getApplicationIcon(appInfo.processName);
                        logo = ((BitmapDrawable) icon).getBitmap();
                        CharSequence c = pm.getApplicationLabel
                        (
                                pm.getApplicationInfo(appInfo.processName,PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)
                        );

                        pids[0] = appInfo.pid;

                        nombrePaquete = appInfo.processName;

                        android.os.Debug.MemoryInfo[] memoryInfoArray = activityManager.getProcessMemoryInfo(pids);
                        for(android.os.Debug.MemoryInfo pidMemoryInfo: memoryInfoArray)
                        {
                            memoria = (float)pidMemoryInfo.getTotalPss()/1024;

                            if(pidMemoryInfo.getTotalPss()/1024 <= 3)
                            {
                                listaapps.add(new Apps(bandaVerde,  logo  ,  c.toString() , memoria  ,logoDelete, nombrePaquete, new File(getActivity().getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(nombrePaquete, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA).publicSourceDir)));
                            }
                            else if((pidMemoryInfo.getTotalPss()/1024 >= 7))
                            {
                                listaapps.add(new Apps(bandaRoja,  logo  ,  c.toString() , memoria  ,logoDelete,nombrePaquete, new File(getActivity().getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(nombrePaquete, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA).publicSourceDir)));
                            }                   
                            else if((pidMemoryInfo.getTotalPss()/1024 > 3 && pidMemoryInfo.getTotalPss()/1024 < 7))
                            {
                                listaapps.add(new Apps(bandaNaranja,  logo  ,  c.toString() , memoria  ,logoDelete,nombrePaquete, new File(getActivity().getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(nombrePaquete, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA).publicSourceDir)));
                            }   
                        }

                        cont++;
                        MB += memoria;

                        if(cont % 2 == 0)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                publishProgress();
                            }
                            catch(IllegalStateException e){}
                        }

                    }
                } 
                catch (Exception e) {}
            }
            cont = 0;
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(ArrayList<Apps>... values)
        {   
            try
            {
               adaptadorLista = new AdaptadorListaApps(activity,listaapps);
               listaAplicaciones.setAdapter(adaptadorLista);
                       adaptadorLista.notifyDataSetChanged();           
            }
            catch(IllegalStateException e){}
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
        {
            adaptadorLista = new AdaptadorListaApps(activity,listaapps);
            adaptadorLista.sort(new OrderList());   
            listaAplicaciones.setAdapter(adaptadorLista);
        }
    }
```

Please, help me... Thanks

Comment: You must notify your `Adapter` from your main UI Thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never change the properties of a view or any of its underlying datasource on a background thread.

1. Do not manipulate the variable `listaaps` in your `onBackground`. Only change it in your `onPostExecute` or `onProgressUpdate`.
2. Do not manipulate the variable `adaptorLista` in your `onBackground`. Only change it in your `onPostExecute` or `onProgressUpdate`.